# Newtonsoft.Json on Xamarin - Unexpected Member Type

Tags: xamarin, json.net

I've started seeing a strange exception when I recently upgraded the Newtonsoft.Json package in my Xamarin Forms project to v8.0.1.  I'm seeing the same issue in three different projects when I try to deserialize objects.  It doesn't happen with every single call to deserialize but it happens consistently with specific calls.

These are all projects where the code hasn't changed and I don't believe the JSON has changed so this looks to me like an issue with either Newtonsoft or Xamarin?

Is anyone else seeing this issue?

**Exception Details:**

- Source: Newtonsoft.Json
- Message: Unexpected member type.
- StackTrace:

> Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.TypeExtensions.TestAccessibility
>   (System.Reflection.MemberInfo member, BindingFlags bindingFlags)
>   [0x0003f] in :0    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.TypeExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass34_0.b__0
>   (System.Reflection.MemberInfo m) [0x00013] in :0
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereListIterator`1[TSource].MoveNext ()
>   [0x00048] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/2377/73229919/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs:232
>   at System.Linq.Buffer`1[TElement]..ctor (IEnumerable`1 source)
>   [0x00083] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/2377/73229919/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs:2570
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource] (IEnumerable`1 source)
>   [0x00011] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/2377/73229919/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs:830
>   at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.TypeExtensions.GetMember (System.Type
>   type, System.String member, BindingFlags bindingFlags) [0x00030] in
>   :0    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.TypeExtensions.GetMember (System.Type type,
>   System.String name, MemberTypes memberType, BindingFlags bindingFlags)
>   [0x0000d] in :0    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ReflectionUtils.GetMemberInfoFromType
>   (System.Type targetType, System.Reflection.MemberInfo memberInfo)
>   [0x00066] in :0    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonTypeReflector.GetAttribute[T]
>   (System.Reflection.MemberInfo memberInfo) [0x0005f] in :0    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonTypeReflector.GetAttribute[T]
>   (System.Object provider) [0x0001b] in :0    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.GetSerializableMembers
>   (System.Type objectType) [0x000cf] in :0    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CreateProperties
>   (System.Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization) [0x00000]
>   in :0    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CreateObjectContract
>   (System.Type objectType) [0x00035] in :0    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CreateContract
>   (System.Type objectType) [0x000c9] in :0    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.ResolveContract
>   (System.Type type) [0x00038] in :0    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.GetContractSafe
>   (System.Type type) [0x00005] in :0    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateList
>   (IList list, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader,
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonArrayContract contract,
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerProperty,
>   System.String id) [0x00052] in :0    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList
>   (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType,
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract,
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, System.Object
>   existingValue, System.String id) [0x000dc] in :0
>   at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal
>   (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType,
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract,
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member,
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract containerContract,
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerMember,
>   System.Object existingValue) [0x0007f] in :0    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue
>   (Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty property,
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter propertyConverter,
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract containerContract,
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerProperty,
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Object target) [0x00061] in
>   :0    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject
>   (System.Object newObject, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader,
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonObjectContract contract,
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, System.String id)
>   [0x00220] in :0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a known bug.

Use 7.0.1 until 8.0.2 is released - https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/771